# How to have unique primary key in two tables?

Tags: oracle, unique, primary-key

I have two tables in my system `EMPLOYEE` and `EMPLOYEE_FORECAST`. Both have the same columns, entire structure is same. I have another archive table with same structure called `EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE` table.

I need to put data from both tables to this archive table. Since records in `EMPLOYEE` and `EMPLOYEE_FORECAST` may have same primary key e.g. a record in `EMPLOYEE` will have a pk of say 100 and another record in `EMPLOYEE_FORECAST` may also have pk of 100 and this will definitely happen so when they are inserted into archive table I will have a duplicate primary key.

The problem is I will also have some relation table like `employee_products`, `employee_forecast_products` and also `employee_archive_products`. These tables will have `emp_id` and `product_id`. So with same `emp_id` I wont be able to figure out the exact employee.

So, is there any way to have a unique primary key both the `EMPLOYEE` and `EMPLOYEE_FORECAST` tables.

Comment: Create a derived primary key on the archive table, perhaps with the name of the table the record came from and make the PK for the archive table both the original table name and the original table PK value.

Comment: After reading your update, it looks like you might want to rethink your database design rather than hash together a workaround.

Comment: @Ollie. Basically forecast table will have forecasted data and I dont want to put it in live data as forecast data may or may not be correct. Otherwise I would have haver them in same table.

Comment: Perhaps seperate your forecase and actual tables into seperate schemas each with their own archive tables. It'll give you a good logical seperation and you can always retrieve joined datasets by querying both schemas if needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to design a data model that deals with the current employees and forecasted employees?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332611/how-to-design-a-data-model-that-deals-with-the-current-employees-and-forecasted)

Comment: I am voting to close this question because Ashish has posted a new question with a better definition of the actual requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So you cannot not use the PK column of EMPLOYEE table as a PK column of the archive table.

You can add a new PK column to the archive table.

If, for some reason, you want the EMPLOYEE table's PK column to be the PK in the archive table, then you could add a flag column to the archive table which would indicate from which table the record comes from. And you could have a composite PK in the archive table containing the original PK and the flag column. (In general, I discourage composite PK-s, so, even if you want to have this flag column, you could have an additional normal PK column in the archive as well.)

Comment: I dont want the EMPLOYEE table's PK column to be the PK in the archive table. But But my archive table will have different column called emp_id  and when I put rows from both the tables in here archive table. This column should ahve the PKs from the two tables. and which should be unique.

Comment: I agree with all, but one: why should be the emp_id column in the archive table unique?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, set up you archive table as:

```
EMPLOYEE
EMPID   NUMBER PK
EMPNAME VARCHAR2(30)
...

EMPLOYEE_FORECAST
EMPID   NUMBER PK
EMPNAME VARCHAR2(30)
...

EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE
ORIG_TABLE VARCHAR2(30) PK
EMPID      NUMBER       PK
EMPNAME    VARCHAR2(30)
...
```

Data in `EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE`:

```
ORIG_TABLE        EMPID      EMPNAME
------------------------------------
EMPLOYEE          100        JO BLOGGS
EMPLOYEE_FORECAST 100        JO BLOGGS
```

As the archive table PK is across both the original table and empid columns it will remain unique for all your data.

Obviously this is just an example and you can use whatever derived column you want to enforce the uniqueness in your archive table.

Hope it helps...

Comment: See I have updated my question. With this I will also need to add ORG_TABLE IN all my relation table also.

Comment: Having seen your update and comment on APC's answer about seperate employees having the same `emp_id`, i would say your issue is not with how you store your archive data but more with your data model. Giving two employees the same `emp_id` is setting yourself up for a headache and a lot of extra work in the coding of your application.

Comment: I completely agree with what you are saying. But the problem is as I said in comment above I may not have full details of employee while forecasting not even name. and this may be even wrong. Like if in april I say 10 employee will join in august not knowing their details, I still enter them in db. Thne in May i come to know not 10 but only five will join in august. So I go and delete 5 of those 10.  But I would still want to know in reports what was my forecast in April i.e. it was 10. And hence the seprate table and then the archive table.

Comment: Please see I have added another question with the data design that is required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332611/how-to-design-a-data-model-that-deals-with-the-current-employees-and-forecasted

Comment: @Ashish, could you not assign all employees (forecast and current) an emp_id from the same sequence so all emp_id's are then unique? In fact put all employees in the same table and give them a flag to denote whether they are foreacst or current?

Comment: May be. But now I really want to rethink my data model.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Common Super-Table. Make another table EMPLOYEE_ID with only a primary key. Let both EMPLOYEE, EMPLOYEE_FORECAST and EMPLOYEE_ARCHIVE reference it.

Comment: @A Smit. is it possible to create a system generated GUID and put as PK in both the table while inserting new records. This will be the emp_id both the tables whichh will be unique. I guess GUID are unqiue always.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model seems a tad confused.  If EMPLOYEE and EMPLOYEE_FORECAST have identical structures why have two tables?  What is the business rule here?

And if they are supposed to be two separate tables why store them in a common archive table?  Why not have separate archives for each table?

I agree with @Ollie.  You need to rethink your data model so it clearly expresses how your business operates.  If you post your business rules here I'm sure we can help you untangle things.  But here is probably the crucial question: do the following keys identify one employee (i.e one person in the real world) or two?

```
employee.emp_id = 100
employee_forecast.emp_id = 100
```

Comment: These will be different employees.

Comment: @Ashish, this changes a lot and asks a lot more of your data model. Giving two seperate employees the same `emp_id` is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Ollie So what do you guys suggest keeping them in the same table. But in that case forecast emps may not have full details. And the forecast may keep on changing per month.

Comment: @APC Please see I have added another question with the data design that is required http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332611/how-to-design-a-data-model-that-deals-with-the-current-employees-and-forecasted