# How to design a data model that deals with the current employees and forecasted employees?

Tags: oracle, database-design

We are creating an application to manage the employees. The employees can be curent employees or the employees which are going to join in future (forecast).

Apart from managing employees we also have to manage the forecast on monthly basis.

Assuming today is April,

Currrent employee strength is 100 as Of 26th April.

Today, I predict 10 people will join in August. 20 Will join in November.

When I say I predict I actually go and add 10 and 20 employees in system. I may or may not have full information. I may not even have names as They are not hired yet. But I just predict that there will be 10 hires in August and 20 in November as on April.

Assuming there are no more leavers or joiners in between. My employee strength by end of August will be 110 and by end of November will be 130.

So, 110 in August and 130 in November is my prediction in the month of april.

Now, In May I come  to know that in august instead of 10 only 5 are joining and in november instead of 20 , 25 will be joining plus we will be firing 10 existing employees in december.

So my employees count as predicted in may will be 105 in August, 130 in november and 120 in december.

So, I need to keep the employee data monthwise i.e. what was my prediction in april for the every single future month i.e. from may to december.

again, what was my prediction in may for august to december.

and so on.

I also need to keep in mind that the data of the existing employees may keep on chnaging every single minute.

Their title may change, address may change, department etc.

So if employee A is in department D1 in April and D2 after April.

When I pull out a report for April it should show me as D1 and when I pull out a report for June , it should show me his department as D2.

Please help.

---

There is some additional background in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10331265/146325).

EDIT :

Please see the following image.

I would want to know the count of the employees as predicted in march (For Month = March) in each sub sequent months i.e. in for month  = march , count in march = 400, count in April = 405.

The numbers in the bracket shows the new employees who will be joining in that month  e.g. (+10) & (-5) shows employees leaving in that month. So If in march total employees are 400 and 10 are joining and 5 are leaving in April then total count will be 405 in April.

[image]

Comment: You really ought to read the FAQ.  The point of SO is to provide a permanent source of high quality answers to the wider internet  community.  Frankly nobody cares whether you need this urgently.

Comment: @Ashish, if this is that urgent, you should consider paying a consultant to help out rather than waiting on the good will of the SO community. (Though being a consultant myself, i'm a little biased).

Answer (score 2):

I can see a couple of reasons you need two tables for this:

- real employees must have a name, a department etc while forecast employees only may have these attributes
- there will be responsibilities that only real employees can have, so you want to be able to reference them separately

But at the same time you want to ensure that there is no clash of IDs across the two tables, becausee (hopefully) forecast employees will become actual employee.

The way to do this is to implement a super-type/sub-type structure.  So you have one table, EMPLOYEES which guarantees single primary keys, and two dependent tables for actual and forecast employees.  The use of the type column is crucial, as it ensures that a given employee only appears in one sub-table.

```
create table employees
    ( emp_id number not null
      , emp_type varchar2(8) not null
      , constraint emp_pk primary key (emp_id)
      , constraint emp_uk unique (emp_id, emp_type)
      , constraint emp_type_ck check (emp_type in ('FORECAST', 'ACTUAL'));

create table actual_employees
    ( emp_id number not null
      , emp_type varchar2(8) not null
      , name varchar2(30) not null
      , deptno number(2,0) not null
      , sal number(7,2) not null
      , hiredate date not null
      , constraint actemp_pk primary key (emp_id)
      , constraint actemp_type_ck check (emp_type = 'ACTUAL')
      , constraint actemp_emp_fk foreign key (emp_id, emp_type)
                   references emp (emp_id, emp_type) 
                   deferrable initially deferred ;

create table forecast_employees
    ( emp_id number not null
      , emp_type varchar2(8) not null
      , name varchar2(30) 
      , deptno number(2,0) 
      , sal number(7,2) 
      , predicted_joining_date date
      , constraint foremp_pk primary key (emp_id)
      , constraint foremp_type_ck check (emp_type = 'FORECAST')
      , constraint foremp_emp_fk foreign key (emp_id, emp_type)
                   references emp (emp_id, emp_type) 
                   deferrable initially deferred ;
```

So the  keys might look a bit odd.  The parent table has both a primary key and a compound unique key.  The primary key guarantees a single instance of the EMP_ID.  The unique key allows us to build foreign keys on the child tables which reference both the EMP_ID and the EMP_TYPE.  Combined with the check contraints on the child t
This is because they reference the unique key on the parent table rather than its primary key.  ables this arrangement ensures that an employee can be in either FORECAST_EMPLOYEES or ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES but not both.

The foreign keys are deferrable to allow the conversion of forecast employees to actual employess.  This requires three activities:

1. deleting the record from FORECAST_EMPLOYEES
2. inserting a record into ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES
3. changing the EMP_TYPE (but *not* the EMP_ID) in EMPLOYEES.

Synchronising actions 2 and 3 is easier with deferred constraints.

Also, note that other foreign key constraints referencing EMPLOYEES should use the primary key rather than the  unique key.  If the relationship cares about the type of employee than it probably should link to the child tables instead.

---

> "so bit of headache"

Welcome to the world of data modelling.  It's one big headache.  Because trying to fit messy reality into a clean data model is *hard*: you need clear requirements to get it right, and an understanding of what matters most so you can make sensible compromises.

I proposed a super-type/sub-type approach on the basis of your other question, and because it seems to be the best way handling two sets of data: real employees and notional employees.  I think those two groups need to be treated differently.  For instance, I would insist on managers being real employees.  This is easy to do with an integrity constraint against ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES and way harder to achieve with a single table which contains both types of employees.

Sure having two tables means possibly generates more work with regards to synchronising their structures. So what?  It's largely trivial, as it is barely more work to write two ALTER TABLE statements than one.   Plus it is quite possible that the new column applies only to actual employees and is of no meaning to forecast employees (e.g. EARNED_COMMISSION, LAST_REVIEW_RATING).  In that light having separate tables makes the data model more accurate.

With regards to having to duplicate dependent tables, as Ollie points out, that is a misunderstanding.  Tables which apply to all employees regardless of their actuality shoudl reference the EMPLOYEES table not its children.

Finally I don't understand why maintaining historical data is harder with two tables than for one.  Most journaling code should be wholly generated from the data dictionary.

---

> "if i have Employee table and Employee_forecast table ... "

There are *three* tables:

- EMPLOYEES - a master table to guarantee unique EMP_IDs
- ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES - a child table for people who work for your company
- FORECAST_EMPLOYEES - a child table for people who you hope to recruit to your company

> "... both of their products or activities will be stored in one single
>   product/ activity table?"

Please bear in mind that I am making assumptions about your business logic from the scant details you have provided.

Now it seems to me that people who don't yet work for your company should not have any  associated activities.  In that scenario you would have one table, EMPLOYEE_ACTIVITIES,  which is a child of ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES.

But perhaps you do genuinely have activities for people who don't exist.  So here's a choice: one table or two?  The one table design has EMPLOYEE_TASKS as a child of the master EMPLOYEES table.  The two table design has ACTUAL_EMPLOYEE_TASKS and FORECAST_EMPLOYEE_TASKS as children of the ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES and FORECAST_EMPLOYEES tables respectively.

Which design is the correct one depends on whether you need to enforce rules regarding assignemnt of tasks.  For instance, your company might have a rule which states that only real people can hire new staff.  So it would be useful to have a model that only allows recruitment tasks to be assigned to ACTUAL_EMPLOYEES.

---

> "this design does not have any considerations for the monthwise
>   forecast"

Okay I have added date columns to the two tables.  That will allow you to run the report you want.

Comment: I might also have some refrence tables for each of the employee type. Say employee_products. So I will need to have two seprate tables for actual employees and then one more for the forecast employee. If in future I add one more refrence table to actual employee I will also have to add it to forecast table. Plus if ther are some column chnages in actual employee I will have to keep them in sync with the forecast table. Plus the changes on these tables need to be audited as I need to maintain historical data also. so bit of headache if I keep them seperate. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Ashish, if they are just reference tables then link them to the `EMPLOYEE` tables, I'd see no reason to have a reference table specifically per `EMPLOYEE` table as such. If you need to add employee columns then that's a different issue.

Comment: @APC, +1 for this...."Welcome to the world of data modelling. It's one big headache" :-)

Comment: @APC So you mean to say if i have Employee table and Employee_forecast table , both of their products or activities will be stored in one single product/ activity table?

Comment: @APC Also, this design does not have any considerations for the monthwise forecast as I had said in my question. The is not just about having unique ids for actual and forecast employees. But also about having all infomatio of actual and forecast emlpoyees on monthly basis. i.e. Count of all employees (both) as predicted in March (for months of april, May, ... dec),  Count of all employees (both) as predicted in April (for months of May, June, july ... dec) and so on. e.g. As per march Count in April = 400, may = 410, June = 430 but count as per April in May = 405, june = 440.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that your data model will depend upon what information you need to report on.
For example, I would be inclined to have the standard `EMPLOYEE` and `DEPARTMENT` tables (like the Oracle default `SCOTT` schema).

I would also have a status column where you could denote an employee is a current employee or a prospective employee thereby allowing you to report on current hires and forecast hires. You could add functional constraints/business rules around what columns are required depending upon the status of the employee etc. so current employees would have full names, DOB etc whereas prospective employees might not.

I would also then create an audit table to track the changes the `EMPLOYEE` record undergoes. This would allow you to retrospectively find their department changes and when the record employee changed from a prospective to current employee etc. as awell as any changes to other data within the `EMPLOYEE` record.
It would also have the advantage of keeping all your data in one location. You could also consider partitioning the `EMPLOYEE` table using the status column if needed.

This would give you the benefit of only ever issuing a single ID to each employee throughout their process through the various stages of employment in your application.

Another benefit of the status column is that you could then introduce any other stages an employee could go through as needed in the future.

**EDIT:**

This would also ensure that if you needed to add columns in the future as you mentioned, you only have to support one table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:
Employee and Department table as typical, but no dept_id in emp table
have a emp_dept table to represent the many to many between employee and department with an effective date or effective date range for the relationship.
for perspective_employees, I'd recommend a separate table with date in it, then union in that with employee table when you need that info.

Hard to get real detailed here, but I hope you get the basics of what I'm saying.

Regards,
Roger

Comment: Thaanks for the reply. But my employee table may have 20 columns which may need to tracked like department. Say city, state, country, region, division, product, designation etc. So do I need to have a seprate table for each of those columns?

Comment: Well, you could put the effective date or effective date range in the employee table in that case.